# MasterDetail ToolbarItem present in Detail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetailPage and I put a ToolbarItem in the parent controller, but it appears in the Detail as well. Any ideas why?

```
<MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="addMeterReading" Order="Primary" Icon="add.png" Text="Add Reading" Priority="0" Clicked="NewMeterReading_Clicked" />  
</MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[image]

Comment: Because it is in the MasterDetail, which is the parent. If you only want to show it on a single page, add it to that particular page.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Im a little confused. My code inits a new `MeterReadingsMasterDetailPage` and presents it. That is also where I want the `ToolbarItem` to be. So there is no other page to put it in. Unless I am using `MasterDetailPage` wrong?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Even if I add it to `App._NavPage.ToolbarItems` it still shows up in the MasterDetail...

Comment: Add it only in the page you need it that you set as detail view

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I want it in the same Toolbar as the Back button and not in the detail

Answer (score 0):

In you detail page, not in your master page. Add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" "
        x:Class="MyProject.MyPage">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem  
                Name="addMeterReading" 
                Order="Primary" 
                Icon="add.png" 
                Text="Add Reading" 
                Priority="0" 
               Clicked="NewMeterReading_Clicked" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    </ContentPage>
```